# difference of each two elements of a column in the matrix

Tags: matlab, merge, diff

I have a matrix like this:

```
fd = 

x   y   z
2   5   10
2   6   10
3   5   11
3   9   11
4   3   11
4   9   12
5   4   12
5   7   13
6   1   13
6   5   13
```

I have two parts of my problem:

1) I want to calculate the difference of each two elements in a column.
So I tried the following code:

```
for i= 1:10

n=10-i;

for j=1:n

    sdiff1 = diff([fd(i,1); fd(i+j,1)],1,1);
    sdiff2 = diff([fd(i,2); fd(i+j,2)],1,1);
    sdiff3 = diff([fd(i,3); fd(i+j,3)],1,1);

end

end
```

I want all the differences such as:

```
  x1-x2, x1-x3, x1-x4....x1-x10
  x2-x3,  x2-x4.....x2-x10
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  x9-x10
```

same for y and z value differences

Then all the values should stored in sdiff1, sdiff2 and sdiff3

2) what I want next is for same z values, I want to keep the original data points. For different z values, I want to merge those points which are close to each other. By close I mean,

```
if abs(sdiff3)== 0
keep the original data

for abs(sdiff3) > 1
if abs(sdiff1) < 2 & abs(sdiff2) < 2
```

then I need mean x, mean y and mean z of the points.

So I tried the whole programme as:

```
for i= 1:10

    n=10-i;

    for j=1:n

    sdiff1 = diff([fd(i,1); fd(i+j,1)],1,1);
    sdiff2 = diff([fd(i,2); fd(i+j,2)],1,1);
    sdiff3 = diff([fd(i,3); fd(i+j,3)],1,1);

       if (abs(sdiff3(:,1)))> 1


               continue

    mask1 = (abs(sdiff1(:,1)) < 2) & (abs(sdiff2(:,1)) < 2) & (abs(sdiff3:,1)) > 1);
    subs1 = cumsum(~mask1);

    xmean1 = accumarray(subs1,fd(:,1),[],@mean);
    ymean1 = accumarray(subs1,fd(:,2),[],@mean);
    zmean1 = accumarray(subs1,fd(:,3),[],@mean);
    fd = [xmean1(subs1) ymean1(subs1) zmean1(subs1)];


       end 
    end

end
```

My final output should be:

```
2.5   5   10.5
3.5   9   11.5
5     4   12
5     7   13
6     1   13
```

where, (1,2,3),(4,6),(5,7,10) points are merged to their mean position (according to the threshold difference <2) whereas 8 and 9th point has their original data.

I am stuck in finding the differences for each two elements of a column and storing them. My code is not giving me the desired output.
Can somebody please help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the actual datasize for `fd` you are working with? Is it  really `10 x 3`?

Comment: to find all possible differences, use matlab combination to group them: nchoosek

Comment: No my actual datasize is 2609 x3. I just tried with a small part @Divakar

Comment: How nchoosek going to give me the differences within the column? It is only for choosing combination of elements right? @qmeeeeeee

Comment: This should perform the matrix subtraction that you're looking for.

xdiffs = bsxfun( @minus, x, x');

Comment: I tried running xdiffs = bsxfun( at minus, fd(i,1), fd(i+j,1)); inside the loop. it is returning a single value. Can you please help @siliconwafer ?

Comment: I don't think you need the loop if you use bsxfun

Comment: Then how should I specify x and x'? They belong to the same column of same matrix.@siliconwafer

Comment: @nabaneeta mukhopadhyay to answer, try to following example: a=[2,0,1,5]; b=[0,4,2,9]; v=[1:4]; test = nchoosek(v,2); a(test(:,1)) - b(test(:,2)). ans provides  2-4, 2-2,2-9, 0-2,0-9 etc as you specified. This method is hundreds of times faster than the looping method.

Comment: thanks for the answer @qmeeeeeee but this is not what I am looking for. nchoosek(v,2) will choose all the possible pairs between the two matrices. What I want is to choose all possible pairs from a column of a matrix. If you have some idea how it will work on the type of data set I provided here, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This can be greatly simplified using vectorised notation. You can do for instance

```
fd(:,1) - fd(:,2)
```

to get the difference between columns 1 and 2 (or equivalently `diff(fd(:,[1 2]), 1, 2)`). You can make this more elegant/harder to read and debug with `pdist` but if you only have three columns it's probably more trouble than it's worth.

I suspect your first problem is with the third argument to `diff`. If you use `diff(X, 1, 1)` it will do the first order diff in direction 1, which is to say between adjacent rows (downwards). `diff(X, 1, 2)` will do it between adjacent columns (rightwards), which is what you want. Matlab uses the opposite convention to spreadsheets in that it indexes rows first then columns.

Once you have your diffs you can then test the elements:

```
thesame = find(sdiff3 < 2); % for example
```

this will yield a vector of the row indices of sdiff3 where the value is less than 2. Then you can use

```
fd(thesame,:)
```

to select the elements of fd at those indexes. To remove matching rows you would do the opposite test

```
notthesame = find(sdiff > 2);
```

to find the ones to keep, then extract those into a new array

```
keepers = fd(notthesame,:);
```

These won't give you the exact solution but it'll get you on the right track. For the syntax of these commands and lots of examples you can run e.g. `doc diff` in the command window.

Comment: I am sorry may be I am not understanding your answer completely. I don't want to compare the adjacent columns. I want to compare all the elements in each row of a column. I want to compare all the x's with each other. then all the y and then all the z. @xenoclast

Comment: Sorry that was my fault - I misread the question. In this case `pdist` is indeed what you want to use.

Comment: I have another query. pdist returns a vector containing all the pairwise distance. Can I run it for each column? How am I suppose to differentiate which pair of diff x,diff y is corresponding to which diff z? I am a newbie in matlab. please help. @xenoclast

Comment: Yes, if you do `sdiff1 = pdist(fd(:,1))` you will get x2-x1, x3-x1, ... x10-x9, 45 values in all. To get the y column use `fd(:,2)` and so on. One of the most useful things you can do as a new matlab user is read up on matlab's way of indexing values, it's fundamental to a lot of the tool's power http://uk.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html

Comment: Thanks @xenoclast. I have almost solved it. Only thing is fd(:,thesame) is not working as you suggested. It says Index exceeds matrix dimensions. Can you please suggest how I can get the elements for  thesame = find(sdiff3 >1);

Comment: Try fd(thesame,:) - typo on my part. I've updated the answer to reflect the correct order.

Comment: That gives the same error. can you please try it on the data set? @xenoclast

Comment: I did but the problem is that we've diverged from the question quite a way now, so I don't have the code that produces the error. You can use `size(fd)` to get the size of your fd matrix, and if you list the contents of `thesame` you will be able to see if there are index values that exceed the size of the array. One possibility: you want to remove rows for which the value in any column is a duplicate? If you test all three columns first and then start removing rows your matrix will get shorter and the indexes will no longer apply.

Comment: size(fd) is 10x3 and pdist will generate 10C2 = 45 combinations for each column. So in any case the dimension will be different. I am still not clear how to get the elements corresponding to the pdist values. I am ok if I get a 45x3 matrix. I can work on the elimination further on that. But I can't generate the 45x3 matrix with the original elements corresponding to the 45x3 pdist matrix. Stuck for a long time. Please help @xenoclast.

Comment: Of course... forgot about `squareform`. We shouldn't really be carrying on this discussion in the comments, it's bad form - and because I can't see your code I make silly mistakes like this. I would call squareform on the output of pdist, this will give you a triangular matrix which contains the pairwise distances. You can do >1 on that and get a logical matrix of the same size, then you can recover the indexes that are the same. You'd need some way of deciding which ones to remove. If you have problems with that I think it would worth starting a new question. Good luck!